# Set Environment Variables without conversion between a String and Integer

Tags: ruby

When i set ENV Variables, I get this error:

> no implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError)

This is how I am doing it:

```
ENV["keyone"] = "valueone" //works fine
ENV["keytwo"] = 2 // error!
```

How can I resolve this? I would prefer to **NOT** change type of 2 (using 2.to_s) as it will cause issues down the line for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ENV[]` [can only be used to set strings](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/ENV.html#class-ENV-label-Valid+Names+and+Values):

> Each name or value must be one of the following:
>
> - A String.
> - An object that responds to #to_str by returning a String, in which case that String will be used as the name or value.

So you must use strings and then convert them to integers when reading them. Environment variables set in your shell will always be strings so you should expect that all values in `ENV` are strings as well, for safety.

If you want a more groomed environment then use something like [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to manage it.